# Modifiying characters in a string practice

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

people of this awesome site.

I've been reading and practicing some Javascript since two weeks ago or so. I discovered a website called [codeWars](http://www.codewars.com) after completing the JS course in CodeAcademy. I'm struggling with one of the practices. My code works using the console or JSfiddle and I would like to know why is not working. Also, I know this code is a wee bit dodgy, could you guys give me some advice?

Thanks

Statement:

Create a function called encode() to replace all the lowercase vowels in a given string with numbers according to the following pattern:

a -> 1, e -> 2, i -> 3, o -> 4, u -> 5

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqr4tta9/1/)

```
    function encode(word) {
        var repa = /a/gi;
        var repe = /e/gi;
        var repi = /i/gi;
        var repo = /o/gi;
        var repu = /u/gi;

        word = word.toLowerCase();
        len = word.length;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (word[i] === 'a') {
                word = word.replace(repa, '1');
            }
            else if (word[i] === 'e') {
                word = word.replace(repe, '2');
            }
            else if (word[i] === 'i') {
                word = word.replace(repi, '3');
            }
            else if (word[i] === 'o') {
                word = word.replace(repo, '4');
            }
            else if (word[i] === 'u') {
                word = word.replace(repu, '5');
            }
        }
        return word;
    }
```

Thank you for your time, guys.

Comment: How do you know it is not working? Are you receiving any error messages? How are you attempting to call the encode() function within your page?

Comment: str.replace(/([aeiou])/g, function(j,a){return {a:1,e:2,i:3,o:4,u:5}[a]});

Comment: @DanielSanchez what the page says is "Test didn't pass: Unknown error"

I'm calling the function like this:  encode("something");

I don't know if it means that I have to complete the challenge in a different way or if it's just my code, that sucks or something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I edited your fiddle and it seemed to be working fine?

You just weren't calling your function or printing out the results.

I've added my own fiddle that just calls the function and alerts the values:

```
function encode(word) {
    var repa = /a/gi;
    var repe = /e/gi;
    var repi = /i/gi;
    var repo = /o/gi;
    var repu = /u/gi;

    word = word.toLowerCase();
    len = word.length;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (word[i] === 'a') {
            word = word.replace(repa, '1');
        } else if (word[i] === 'e') {
            word = word.replace(repe, '2');
        } else if (word[i] === 'i') {
            word = word.replace(repi, '3');
        } else if (word[i] === 'o') {
            word = word.replace(repo, '4');
        } else if (word[i] === 'u') {
            word = word.replace(repu, '5');
        }
    }
    return word;
}

alert(encode('aeiou'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rollyourowned/Lj6pmexL/2/

To get a little but not too much smarter with it you could do something like this instead:

```
function encode(word) {

    var letterArray = {a:1,e:2,i:3,o:4,u:5};

    word = word.toLowerCase();
    len = word.length;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

     var re = new RegExp(word[i], "gi");
     word = word.replace(re, letterArray[word[i]]);

    }
    return word;
}

alert(encode('aeiou'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rollyourowned/kotLa70g/

Comment: Thank you very much, @RollYourOwnEd. Now I know that my code works. It's just a problem with the site.

Awesome improvement you did there, I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Absolute pleasure Laura, Have fun with Javascript! :)